# "What is the final will of Victor Porton?" - usage of the word "will"

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning, phrases, legalese

"What is the final will of Victor Porton?", asked one of visitors of my (Victor Porton's) site from my AI chatbot.

Should (supposed that the question was asked by a native speaker) the word "will" here be interpreted in legal sense (as it relates to money, to whom I would give money after death) or in some other way ("what do he wants the most", "what he will desire the last", etc.)? If in other way, please specify.

Comment: I CV'd because there is no way to know which "will" was meant without more context. If you can provide some more context, please do so. Otherwise I think that this question is unanswerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is oddly phrased. To ask about the contents of the legal document one would normally as "What is **in** the will of Victor Porton", but the question as phrased would be addressed to somebody other than Victor Porton.

"What is your will" is an unusual expression these days; "what do you want" or "what would you like" are now much more common ways of expressing the same idea.

"What is your (or his) final will" is also unusual because of the tense. If he is dead the past tense would be used. If he is alive the question would be asked in a future tense, because what he wants now may not be the final thing he wants.

The only sense I can make of the request is that it is asking about the legal document itself. The answer may be "It is final version of the document which specifies how Victor Porton's property is to be distributed after his death".